# Blackberry (Java) - drawing text in two different fonts

Tags: java, blackberry

using the g.drawText function (two calls one for each text) is it possible to write text in two different sizes?

```
g.drawText("abc",0,0);

//whatever code to change font goes here

g.drawText("def",30,30);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The BlackBerry has it's own font classes. Try this:

```
// e.g. serif
FontFamily ff = FontFamily.forName("family-name");

// Use style bits from Font class, e.g. Font.BOLD
Font f = ff.getFont(style, height);
```

If you want to know which FontFamilies are available you can use:

```
FontFamily.getFontFamilies();
```

Comment: Its a good try, but it won't work because the Font classes are different. The one required for the g.setFont is  the net.rim.device.api.ui.Font class but the one with the getFont is the javax.microedition.lcdui.Font class

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!

FYI: As I was not sure what fonts were available, for my POC I simplified to:

FontFamily all[] = FontFamily.getFontFamilies();
FontFamily ff = all[0];